# Script error: Git protocol error - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am doing supervised image classification in Google Earth Engine. For that, I am labeling points on the map to create a dataset. I have labelled around 2.9k points. Now when I am labeling more points and saving the script, I am getting an error that says "Script error: Git protocol error". Hence I am unable to save my work and always starting from the same point. This error is wasting all of my efforts again and again. How can I fix this issue.

Attached is the screenshot of the error for your reference.[image: Script error: Git Protocol Error]

Comment: I am facing same problem.. I have plotted around 2.7k points...

Comment: Check https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues, and if nothing matches, you should create a new issue.